# Testing multiple mac/ip adresses connections

Tags: http, networking, testing

I'm building client-server software (some sort of http Rest API)

And there is a throttling module that prevents one IP to do more then N requests/second

I want to do stress testing of the system - so that I can emulate 100-1000 connections from different IP(or MAC) addresses  (from hardware I have only boxes in one network)

What tools or scripts can I use for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You need certainly a traffic generator, try using this one: http://robert.rsa3.com/traffic.html